# Restreaming video from XSplit to multiple JustinTV/TwitchTV channels in different resolutions and bitrates

Tags: flash-media-server, rtmp, transcoding

I have a really simple question but the answer may be a little more complex I guess.

Okay. Let's go. I have an Application called Xsplit Broadcaster ([http://www.xsplit.com/)](http://www.xsplit.com/). It supports streaming video through RTMP. Now what I want to do is this:

```
                                              +--(720p)--> TwitchTV FirstChannel
XSplit --(720p RTMP)-->[MyTranscodingServer]--+
                                              +--(360p)--> TwitchTV SecondChannel
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Additional info: Both channels accept standard RTMP stream on their RTMP endpoint using either username/password or streamkey. The server operating system is GNU/Linux. The solution may not be paid, otherwise we'd be using AkamaiHD Network or such service. This is a non-profit project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I haven't used it myself, you may want to look into the following [Wowza Transcoder AddOn](http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?304)

Wowza isn't free, I don't know if there are budget restrictions or not?

A very similar question has also been asked on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217389/real-time-transcoding-of-multiple-rtmp-streams), there the OP eventually developed a solution with [GStreamer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/). Their wiki has a page on [transcoding](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/wiki/Transcoding) which may serve as a starting point.

Comment: Updated the question. We don't want to pay for software we can write ourselves (with help of ffmpeg libs)

Comment: Added a free alternative in my solution, although it isn't a complete ready-made solution for your problem it may be easier to implement than ffmpeg.